# AWS Route53 setup and AWS Workmail configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-route53

I have registered a domain with AWS Route53 and have created below setup. My EC2 instance is tied to elastic ip and there is no ELB setup.

```
example.com NS
example.com  A PUBLIC_IP
www.example.com CNAME   example.com.
```

I wanted to setup my email hosting with AWS Workmail and created a domain as example.com so users will have an email address associated with my domain. e.g. adam@example.com. AWS Workmail has created below Route53 entires as part of the setup process.

```
example.com MX  
example.com SOA 
example.com TXT 
_amazonses.example.com  TXT 
_dmarc.example.com  TXT 
argc5..spxi._domainkey.example.com  CNAME   
cmm..3gcb._domainkey.example.com    CNAME   
pw..twuo._domainkey.example.com CNAME   
autodiscover.example.com    CNAME
```

I am able to login to WorkMail and email delivery is working as expected. My issue now is that I cannot access http://example.com or http://www.example.com. I am able to access the site using http://public_ip

Please let me know what is wrong with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an alternate solution to this issue, so I had to create an ELB and create below records in Route53

```
www.example.com CNAME ELB
example.com A (Alias) ELB
```